# How to set proxy on weblogic server 9.2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic9.x

I am using httpurlconnection to post on Facebook,but I am getting following exception

```
 java.net.UnknownHostException: graph.facebook.com
```

might be due to proxy setting,same code running fine while running in a java stand alone application while putting  following

```
 codeProxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,new InetSocketAddress("proxy.domain.com", 8080))
```

Can any one tell how to set proxy on weblogic server?

Comment: Did you use android application?

Comment: No,using j2ee web application

Comment: still not get any reply?

Comment: Do you have a proxy server available?

Comment: @Atiksh you need to tell us how you're setting the proxy information when the webapp is run under Weblogic server.

Comment: @asgs i have  used                                System.getProperties().put("proxyHost", "proxy.domain.com");
System.getProperties().put("proxyPort", "8080"); apart from this i have try also                                                       Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("proxy.domain.com", 8080));

Answer (score 0):

1. Set system properties `http.proxyHost` and `http.proxyPort`. You can do this with `System.setProperty()`, or from the command line with the `-D` syntax. and kindly refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html#Proxies
2. you also need to declare `-DUseSunHttpHandler=true` in the weblogic.
   it will force use sun/oracle `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection` implemention for `java.net.HttpURLConnection` instead of `weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpURLConnection`

try to use connection.usingProxy() to verify the proxy works or not after openConnection();

Answer (score 0):

To configure WebLogic proxy file is modified
setDomainEnv.cmd (Windows) that is located in the bin folder of the domain.

For example for the integrated server is here

```
C: \ Users \ [YOUT USER NAME] \ AppData \ Roaming \ JDeveloper \ system11.1.1.4.37.59.23 \ DefaultDomain \ bin
```

The following property must be placed on file with the details of your proxy

```
@REM Estableciendo proxi
set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Dhttp.proxySet=true -Dhttp.proxyHost=192.168.101.11 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost
```

See the nex link:

[Configure Web Logic Proxi](http://elektro2.blogspot.com/2013/01/configurar-proxy-en-weblogic-para.html)